# How to monitor CPU and system load in GNOME

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

I'm running Debian 10 Buster with GNOME. I'd like to know how to set up some sort of display that shows me the current system load.

In the old days and even in MATE, I can add a System Monitor to my Panel, and then I can configure the System Monitor to show CPU, memory, load, disk, and network.

It would be nice to do something similar in GNOME e.g. on the Top Bar at the top or the Window List at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

[`gnome-system-monitor`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gnome-system-monitor) is similar to [`mate-system-monitor`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/mate-system-monitor) under gnome.

> Process viewer and system resource monitor for GNOME
>
> This package allows you to graphically view and manipulate the running processes on your system. It also provides an overview of available resources such as CPU and memory.

```
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
gnome-system-monitor
```